# Basic JS File Loading but Not Rendering or Executing Laravel 8 Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, bootstrap-5

**Hello,
I have a fresh isntallation of laravel and bootstrap. All I have so far is a navigation bar. When I load the page to see it, I noticed the app.js file loads but does not render the CSS, because the app.css stylesheet is completely empty. Both app.css and app.js are located in the correctly referenced directory. If I use the bootstrap 5 CDN, everything works. In my other project, which is also a fresh installation, the CSS works just fine. I haven't modified this fresh installation.**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('Template 2', 'Template2') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

This is how it compiles in my webpack.mix.json:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```

**Thank you in advance.**

Comment: Have you, and how do you compile? Webpack https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/webpack/ ?

Comment: automatically from the webpack. please see my edit. i follow the usual steps but for some reason this time it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this like so:

i noticed in `public/app.css` it was compiling bootstrap 4.6.

composer require laravel/ui
npm install bootstrap
open `package.json` to ensure the latest version of bootstrap:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
},
```

then I deleted my `public/app.css` and remade a blank app.css
npm run dev mix

hope this helps someone